# How to include icon in the field name of an embed in discord?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I want to have an icon along with the field name in the discord embed using discord.py just like the attached image

[image: Imgur]

I tried solutions like set_images or set_thumbnails from different forums. tried markdown but failed.

Comment: Those are probably custom emojis.  Do you have the source code that produced that embed?

Comment: No, I don't have, If I had that I could satisfy my need :(

Comment: Yeah. This helped me a lot. I managed to do that. This was custom emoji

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Those are custom emojis, There's no way to add images to field(At least for now) unless if you use emojis. Try to hover your mouse cursor over those images, if they display emojis names (starting and ending with ':') then they're emojis
>   (Couldn't comment as i don't have enough reputaions)

Comment: Yeah. This helped me a lot. I managed to do that. This was custom emoji